# Segmentation Fault :- LIBC_FATAL_STDERR

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting the segmentation fault just before the program ends. That is after executing all the statements, i am getting the error.

The code is given below

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int bipartite(int G[1010][1010], int source, int n)
{
int color[n+1];
for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++)
    color[i]=-1;

color[source]=1;
queue<int> q;
q.push(source);

int done=0;
while(done!=1)
{
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (int v = 1; v < n+1; ++v)
        {
            if(u==v)
                continue;
            if (G[u][v] && color[v] == -1)
            {
                color[v] = 1 - color[u];
                q.push(v);
                //cout<<"V PUSH: "<<v<<u<<endl;
            }

            else if (G[u][v] && color[v] == color[u])
            {
                //cout<<"OUT: "<<v<<u<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n+1; i++)
    {
        if(color[i]==-1)
        {
            q.push(i);
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(i==n+2)
        done=1;
}

return 1;
}

int main()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
int n,m,a,b;
int Array[1010][1010];
while(t--)
{
    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i=0; i<=1010; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<=1010; j++)
            Array[i][j]=0;

    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        Array[a][b] = 1;
        Array[b][a] = 1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=1010; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=1010; j++)
        {
            if(Array[i][j]==1)
                Array[i][j]=0;
            else
                Array[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i <=1010; i++)
        Array[i][i]=0;

    if (bipartite(Array, 1, n) == 1)
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    else
        cout << "NO" << endl;

}

cout<<"A"<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

For the input :-
1
3 2
1 2
2 3

The answers are printed correctly but after the i get the seg fault error.

```
The gdb error is Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_getenv (name=0x7ffff76033c2 "BC_FATAL_STDERR_", 
    name@entry=0x7ffff76033c0 "LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_") at getenv.c:84
84  getenv.c: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `int Array[1010][1010];`  Stop doing this and learn to use `std::vector`, as you're probably blowing out the stack.  Same here: `int color[n+1];`  The latter is not valid C++.

Comment: In `main`, `Array` is function scoped (i.e.) on the stack and relatively big for that. It might exceed a limit (i.e. stack overflow). To avoid this [potential, but not only, problem] you could move it to global scope [or use `std::vector` as Paul suggested]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of your array bounds here:

```
for(int i=0; i<=1010; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<=1010; j++)
    Array[i][j]=0;
```

So further you get unpredictable behavior. The correct condition is `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for(int i=0; i<1010; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<1010; j++)
    Array[i][j]=0;
```

Other upper bound check also should be fixed. Everywhere you check it as `<= 1010`, but should be `< 1010`.

In many places you access array elements by index without any checks, it's danger approach.